# Is it possible to rename default "Declarative: Checkout SCM" step?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

When you use Jenkins multibranch pipeline, the first stage is named by default `Declarative: Checkout SCM`.

Is it possible to rename it? I know that it is possible to skip default checkout, but I do not want this - I just want to rename this default step.

Comment: I am looking for renaming only, have you found any solution?

Answer (score 44):

Since noone posted a better solution, I just did it this way:

```
...
options {
    skipDefaultCheckout(true)
}
stages {
    stage('However I want to name a stage') {
        steps {
            checkout scm
...
```

Comment: @Basil this saved me lot's of time! My problem was that some nodes may not checkout the repo per default, because they can't.

Comment: Some other struggeling with SCM might check the hook in the options called `[  ] Lightweight checkout` in pipeline configuration which decides if the full repro is checked out or only the Jenkinsfile is used.